# Large DB import failing, Wamp + PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Trying to reinstall a local copy of my website on a local Wamp server, but after about 30 minutes the DB import keeps failing like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWARs.png

The .GZ file is 125mb and the upload limit is 750mb. According to SELECT statements, wait_timeout is 28800 and max_allowed_packet is 1048576

Those seem to be the two values I've seen referenced in other answers as to be the problem, but they seem sufficiently high here right? What else could it be?

Comment: try to use myql client and command prom fpr that purpose, it has no limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux:

```
$ mysql -u [user] -p [BDD_Name] < YourSQLfile.sql
```

Under Windows:

```
c:\> mysql -u[user] -p [BDD_Name] < YourSQLfile.sql
```

And for a .gz file:

```
zcat YourSQLfile.sql.gz | mysql -u [user] -p [BDD_Name]
```

Comment: well damn that was simple, and uploaded faster than previous via phpmyadmin as well, thanks

Comment: This is usually always the best method (as far as possible) and same for the export (backup) with "mysqldump"
On the other hand, unlike phpMyAdmin, you must not make a mistake in the the BDD name, otherwise it's a tragedy;)